# what to do with island type faces?

Tags: python, mesh, modifiers, 3d-printing

I have a model for 3D printing, to make the model I need to do Boolean operation, after the Boolean, I will have many of this island type faces (like the figure) that I need to get rid of them. the model is big, therefore, manually deleting them is not an option. can anyone suggest me a proper way to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like bad normals and some geometry errors in you model.
Have you tried the classic Select all > Remove Doubles > Recalculate Normals?
(<kbd>A</kbd> to select all > <kbd>W</kbd> > Remove Doubles then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>)

You could then try to use the operator *Select Non Manifold* <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to select said faces, although if they are attached to the rest of the model mesh, deleteing then will most likely create more problems for 3D printing, like wholes and discontinuities.

You could then use the *Select Non Manifold* operator again to detect new problems that might arise and try solve them one by one. Maybe remove doubles and recalculate normals again.

Comment: thank you, I have tried that, however, the problem is that as I try to fix the non-manifolds edges number of intersecting faces increases and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure those are "islands"? I would try and use the smooth brush in sculpt mode. some times you have to deactivate **front faces only**. But if they are indeed "islands" then ultimately they're like doubles or overlapping faces, which could be a pain to get rid of.

Comment: I might have used a wrong word. they might be connected to the other parts, but definitely they are not desirable in the model. I tried the brush but did not help. besides, as I said there are too many of them to handle with brush.